# Not able to set environment variable for sudo -u "user"

Tags: linux, db2, environment-variables, sudo, db2-luw

I am at my wits end trying to figure this out
When I execute the following command:

```
sudo -u icinga '/usr/lib//nagios/plugins/check_db2_health' '--database' 'mydatabase' '--environment' 'DB2DIR=/opt/IBM/db2/V11.1.4fp5a' '--environment' 'DB2INSTANCE=mydatabase' '--environment' 'INSTHOME=/srv/db2/home/mydatabase' '--report' 'short' '--username' 'icinga' '--mode' 'connection-time' '--warning' '50'
```

The output as follow

```
[DBinstance : mydatabase] Status : CRITICAL - cannot connect to mydatabase. install_driver(DB2) failed: Can't load '/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/PerlLib/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/DB2/DB2.so' for module DBD::DB2: libdb2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 190.
 at (eval 10) line 3.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 10) line 3.
Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
 at /usr/lib//nagios/plugins/check_db2_health line 2627.
```

But when I login to the user icinga using **su - icinga**

And run

```
'/usr/lib//nagios/plugins/check_db2_health' '--database' 'mydatabase' '--environment' 'DB2DIR=/opt/IBM/db2/V11.1.4fp5a' '--environment' 'DB2INSTANCE=mydatabase' '--environment' 'INSTHOME=/srv/db2/home/mydatabase' '--report' 'short' '--username' 'icinga' '--mode' 'connection-time' '--warning' '50'
```

It works fine.

How do I setup environment variables when sudo - u icinga command is fired ?
I am on a SUSE linux

I am kind of trying to setup a global environment variable just like the environment variable in icinga which can work across all commands executed on the server without have to use sudo -E etc because I cannot change the way icinga calls the plugin

Comment: what is in the `sudoers` file for `setenv` option? Which security policy plugin (if any) is active?

Comment: @mao can you guide me what to check

Comment: You probably want to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to allow your script to find Db2 libraries.

Comment: or try `sudo -i -u ...`,   __or__ change `check_db2_health` to dot in the correct shell startup script or db2profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to run the db2profile when you sudo

sudo -u icinga sqllib/db2profile; '/usr/lib//nagios/plugins/check_db2_health'  ...